# How to start Scrolling an image from selected image?

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a tableView, which contains image views,say each cell is having 3 imageviews.
Now when I tapp on 5th image (2nd row's 2nd image) it is redirected to another viewcontroller which contains uiscrolleview and in its viewdidload I am loading an array containing all the images of previous controller.It starts scrolling from 1st image. but I want to start it from which image was tapped in previous controller (Here 5th image).